# Переход между activity

Tags: java, android

Есть код 2 активити, они одинаковы с 1, но в первом `spinner`, а во втором `ListView`, так вот в первом у меня парсит 1 `Json` в `spinner`, мне надо, чтобы при нажатие на объект в `spinner`, парсил уже из 2 активити, но в `ListView`.

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String TAG = MainActivity2.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private Spinner spinner;
    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "Тут URL первого Json";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity2.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    JSONArray data = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String ip = c.getString("ip");
                        String link = c.getString("link");
                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("ip", ip);
                        contact.put("link", link);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity2.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"ip", "link",},
                    new int[]{R.id.name,
                            R.id.link});
            spinner.setAdapter((SpinnerAdapter) adapter);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Пока вторая активити не видима на экране, никакого `ListView` не существует в природе. Опишите подробнее, какую задачу вам нужно решить, а не ваш [неправильный] способ ее решения, который вызывает естественные проблемы.

Comment: Ок, мне надо создать `spinner`, в которой парсит `JSON`, когда открывается список, там выбераешь объект, и он парсит другой `JSON`,надеюсь поняли.

Comment: Какое взаимодействие между активити? вы выбираете пункт в спиннере и должно открыться другое активити, в котором через `ListView` отображается дополнительная информация по этому пункту или что?

Comment: да, именно это мне и надо)

Comment: Теперь как связаны данные, которые получает спиннер с теми, который должен отобразить `ListView`? По какому признаку определяется, какой JSON получать для списка?

Comment: Для списка, получает другой `JSON`, но он у всех одинаковый для каждого объекта в `spinner`

Comment: Если нет никакой разницы в отображаемых данных для списка, то просто запускайте второе активити и получайте там свой JSON, затем заполняйте этим список. Проблема в том, что вы не знаете, как запустить второе активити при нажатии на пункт в спиннере?

Comment: Да, вот мне больше это и инересно, как запустить 2 активити

Comment: Это вполне доступно [изложено в официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html?hl=ru#StartingAnActivity), и даже на русском. Более ["разжеваный" пример](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/activity.php)

Comment: `spinner` заработал, но не понял как заупстить второй `activity`

Comment: Вы прочитали инструкции по ссылкам выше? Объяснить понятнее уже вряд ли получится, особенно после второй ссылки.  Что именно вам не понятно?

Comment: ой, я вторую ссылку не видел